# ADODB Command?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm using vb.net. Usually I used the SQL Server SQLComamnd but here I need to use an ADO. 
I have this but I'm stuck at the end of it how to get the data?

```
dim strSQL = "Select Name From tblCustomer Where ID = 123"
cnn.Open()
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
```

How do I actually retrieve this record? 
Is there something akin to the SQLCommand that has Reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's your **Execute** call?

```
Dim results as ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute();
```